# The property Content can only be set once

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm Starting with wpf and i want to work with static resource , when i add the tag  i get an error : The property Content can only be set once , now when i searched on stackoverflow i understood that the window tag can only have one child element, the thing is on the book i'm reading the static resource tag is just above grid tag so how is this working ? here is my code :

```
<Window x:Class="BaseBallSimulator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibilit/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BaseBallSimulator"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <StaticResource></StaticResource>
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="245*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="272*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>      
        <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Trajectory"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Name="TrajectoryTextBox" Text="0" Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="20"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Distance"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Name="DistanceTextBox" Text="0" Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="20"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Name="PlayButton" Content="PRESS To PLAY" Margin="10" Click="PlayButton_Click"  ></Button>
    </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <StackPanel Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Text="Pitcher Says" Margin="5"/>
            <ListView x:Name="PitcherSaysListView" Margin="5" Height="110" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="5,0,5,5">
            <TextBlock Text="Fan Says" Margin="5"/>
            <ListView x:Name="FanSaysListView" Margin="5" Height="110" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why did you add <StaticResource></StaticResource> in the first place? Remove this and it works...

Comment: Yes i know it works but i need a that tag to set a static resource how can do otherwise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<StaticResource></StaticResource>` and your code will compile.

Any resources should be added inside `<Window.Resources>`:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brush" Color="Red" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="245*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="272*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                <TextBlock Text="Trajectory"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox Name="TrajectoryTextBox" Text="0" Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="20"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                <TextBlock Text="Distance"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox Name="DistanceTextBox" Text="0" Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="20"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button Name="PlayButton" Content="PRESS To PLAY" Margin="10"  ></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Pitcher Says" Margin="5"/>
                <ListView x:Name="PitcherSaysListView" Margin="5" Height="110" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Margin="5,0,5,5">
                <TextBlock Text="Fan Says" Margin="5"/>
                <ListView x:Name="FanSaysListView" Margin="5" Height="110" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It doesn't make any sense to define an empty `<StaticResource>` element though.

Comment: I need it to make a static resource

Comment: "It?" What should be a static resource?

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted! mm8's correct about "Remove <StaticResource></StaticResource> and your code will compile."

Comment: Did my part :) Because it compiled for me as well after removing it

Comment: Ohhh my bad i see , Windows.Resource and not static resource . i see how dumb of me , thanks man that resolved it

Answer (score 0):

Static (aswell as dynamic) Resources are managed trough so called Resource Dictionaries. You can either add an explicit resourcedictionary file and reference it somewhere.

Additionally, each UIElement in your XAML can hold its own set of Resources (Static aswell as dynamic). Static and dynamic resources are defined in the exact same manner, the difference lies in how you assign them.

For example you can create a color-resource for the whole window with

```
<Window [...]>
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="myColor">Blue</Color>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Resources defined inside a resource-tag are only visible by the element itself and any children. the `x:Key`-Attribute gives the Resource a name with which you can reference it. You can then consume your resource with

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource myColor}"/>
```

Also, this is the point where you define whether a resource used in a static manner or a dynamic one (using DynamicResource instead). Then you can use the key you set earlier to access your resources.

If you want to change how a specific control looks, e.g. its font size, margins and colors, you can use so called styles instead of assigning every property in a tedious manner. A style is defined exactly the same way as a normal resource

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Note two things: In addition to the `x:Key`-Attribute we specified the `TargetType`-Attribute to tell VisualStudio which element we wish to change. Secondly we use the Setters to change specific properties of that element. To apply a style to a control, simply consume it with

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlock}">My styled Textblock</TextBlock>
```

Bonus: When using Styles you may ommit the `x:Key`-Attribute. This will apply the style automatically to all child controls of type `TargetType`.

Comment: Thanks Man for the Insight that was helpfull